# How can you make an HTML link?

Tags: theming, 8

I need a link with another render array around it. More specifically I need a link around an image.

In the D7 days I'd just use a render array of type link and then set HTML to true and set the text as the image.

I was hoping to put it in a preprocess function.

Comment: Did you try to just pass in a render array? Not everywhere but often, that just works.

Comment: If it doesn't, then rendering it and passing that in should work as that's then a Markup object and will not be further escaped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML attribute removal was documented in [change record #2932803](https://www.drupal.org/node/2392803), but the example uses the now deprecated SafeMarkup::format function. The [FormattableMarkup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Component!Render!FormattableMarkup.php/class/FormattableMarkup/8) class allows a non-deprecated way to do this. The API page has some good examples such as below:

Remember that this is has security implications, and to only use FormattableMarkup when you absolutely need it with strict placeholders.

```
$value = FormattableMarkup::placeholderFormat('<a href=":url">@variable</a>', [':url' => $url, @variable => $variable]);
```

There's probably a better way to do this without printing the anchor element and href attribute yourself.

Comment: Looks like this will be the solution. I was hoping to pass a render array inside the link though. I'll give it a go and feedback.

Comment: I recently discovered [PlaceholderGenerator::createPlaceholder](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!PlaceholderGenerator.php/function/PlaceholderGenerator%3A%3AcreatePlaceholder/8), which might allow that. I have not been able to get it to work inside an Input Filter. However it may actually work outside of an Input Filter as the tests suggest that it should.

Answer (score 3):

That's what worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44163527/1151303

```
    <?php
    use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;
    use Drupal\Core\Url;

    $form['actions']['reset_password'] = [
      '#type' => 'link',
      '#title' => Markup::create(
        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Forgot / Reset Password'
      ), '#url' => Url::fromRoute('user.pass'),
    ];
```